# Oracle - Control access to Database based on user input

Tags: oracle, roles

I need to restrict oracle user (same user) to different data access(views) based on the location he is logging in. ex - company n/w or VPN. As oracle will not be able to identify the network, the idea is to ask user for input location (Home/Office etc).
Based on the input location switch the relevant roles using triggers.

Question is how do i prompt in SQLPLUS and SQLDEVELOPER to select the location just after login.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can check ip address/machine/terminal in login trigger and set required role in it.

Answer (score 0):

Our computers coming from VPNs have a different naming structure than in-house computers. Use the following to get the name of the computer making the connection:

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT( 'USERENV', 'TERMINAL' ) FROM DUAL;
```